# PHPUnit fixture for redis

Tags: redis, phpunit

I wonder if there is an established procedure to create redis fixtures for PHPUnit.
While I can think of at some ways to achieve this, it would be nice to have something standardized.

As I dislike the idea of working with those EOF files directly, I currently use

- either a logfile where I run every line as a single command,
- or a LUA script if I need to generate a lot of predicteable or random lines.

How are you testing scripts incorporating redis? Due to the speed of a local instance, I work with a clean testing instance and consider a mocking of redis clearly overhead.

### How to record and replay redis commands in php

While waiting for your suggestions, I share mine.

To record a logfile of every command entered into redis, you can use the shell:

```
redis-cli monitor > redis.txt
```

Running while normal usage simply generates real-life fixture.

In case you wonder how to turn

```
"HSET" "foobar" "111" "1"  --->  $redis->hset('foobar', '111', '1');
```

use

```
preg_match_all('/"([^\s]+)"/', $line, $matches);

$command_parts = $matches[1];
$command = array_shift($command_parts);
$command = strtolower(trim($command));

call_user_func_array(array($redis, $command), $command_parts);
```

Comment: I think what you're saying is that you don't want to mock out whatever it is that you're using to talk to redis and instead you're planning on talking to to a real live redis instance in your *unit* tests. If that's the case, you're not writing unit tests, you're writing integration tests. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing#Separation_of_interface_from_implementation

Comment: You are partially right Colin, since depending on an external system during the test usually means a shift in focus away from unit towards integration. How ever, it makes little difference if you depend on a 3rd-party-mock-system or a 3rd party live system. My current solution is to use a freshly setup localhost redis instance injected into the system-under-test, and to populate the data from withhin the single test case. As I consider Redis working, there is little drawback in populating a real redis instance instead a mock of one.